# Trigger.io Parse notifications ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, parse-platform, trigger.io

When trying to register to receive notifications using the Parse.com module (https://trigger.io/modules/parse/current/docs/index.html) I receive the following error in trigger.io console. I have tried on Linux and OSX using up to date trigger.io and up to date Android SDK.

Have I missed something in the configuration?

```
[FORGE] 'error subscribing to beta-tester notifications: {"message":"Forge Java error: ClassNotFoundException: Didn\'t find class \\"bolts.Task\\" on path: DexPathList[[zip file \\"/data/app/io.trigger.forge2172634a55fa11e5a76f12313b0234c0-1/base.apk\\"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/io.trigger.forge2172634a55fa11e5a76f12313b0234c0-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]","type":"UNEXPECTED_FAILURE","subtype":null,"full_error":"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn\'t find class \\"bolts.Task\\" on path: DexPathList[[zip file \\"/data/app/io.trigger.forge2172634a55fa11e5a76f12313b0234c0-1/base.apk\\"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/io.trigger.forge2172634a55fa11e5a76f12313b0234c0-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]\\n\\tat dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)\\n\\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)\\n\\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)\\n\\tat com.parse.gz.a(Unknown Source)\\n\\tat com.parse.fb.c(Unknown Source)\\n\\tat com.parse.fb.g(Unknown Source)\\n\\tat com.parse.cx.s(Unknown Source)\\n\\tat com.parse.dt.a(Unknown Source)\\n\\tat com.parse.dr.a(Unknown Source)\\n\\tat com.parse.dr.a(Unknown Source)\\n\\tat io.trigger.forge.android.modules.parse.API.push_subscribe(Unknown Source)\\n\\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)\\n\\tat io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeApp.callJavaFromJavaScript(Unknown Source)\\n\\tat io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeJSBridge$1.run(Unknown Source)\\n\\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)\\n\\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)\\n\\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)\\n\\tSuppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bolts.Task\\n\\t\\tat java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)\\n\\t\\tat java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)\\n\\t\\tat java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)\\n\\t\\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)\\n\\t\\t... 15 more\\n\\tCaused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available\\n"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't read the docs properly. I had failed to add the facebook module https://trigger.io/modules/facebook/current/docs/index.html.

See https://trigger.io/modules/parse/current/docs/index.html.